# FlexTable with Uibinder or alternatives

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, uibinder

What's the best way to use flextable in corperation with uiBinder, I already know that I have to provide it and initiate it befor `initWidget`

```
@UiField(provided = true) FlexTable contentTable;
```

But I simply need a table with as an input matrix like:

```
pseudo:

 Label."Name: " TextBox() 
 Label."Password: " TextBox()
```

Know is it a good idea to even consider FlexTable or is there a better Alternativ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: By the way you don't have to "provide it and initiate it before initWidget"... that's only the case for custom widgets that need constructor args that you could not provide using a UiBinder template(at least in a clean manner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll pass on the fact that using a table for a form layout is not your best option nor a good practice.

You can just use an `HTMLPanel` with UiBinder, and do everything in HTML like you would with a "normal" page, with some additional GWT tags for widgets :

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
   <div class="formInput">
      <g:Label text="First Name - W3C style : ">
      <g:TextBox ui:field="firstNameTextBox">
   </div>


   <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name - table style :</td>
            <td><g:TextBox ui:field="lastNameTextBox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- Other form fields -->
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: thanks. I already did it that way. wasn't sure if it's the best approach, therfore I asked this question :) thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a table to display an input form I would consider the use of a pure HTML widget, made mixing GWT widget, as the folowing.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
         xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<ui:style>

</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <g:TextBox ui:field="name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>
               <g:PasswordTextBox ui:field="password"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </g:HTMLPanel>
 </ui:UiBinder>
```

Prefer FlexTable for displaying Data or editable data. Because it's really fast for displaying those types of information. From what I've seen, excesive use use of widgets slows down the application.